# If I flip my variable in a simple linear regressor, how do I show the $R^2$ are equal?

Tags: regression, r-squared

Initially $y$ is a function of $x$, then $x$ is a function of $y$. Even just a hint would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: The $R^2$ in the linear regression model is equal to $cor(x,y)^2$. Flipping X and Y, gives you exactly the same result

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, $R^2$ in simple linear regression is just the square of the correlation. And the correlation of $\vec x$ with $\vec y$ is

$$ \frac{(\vec x - \bar x) \cdot (\vec y - \bar y)}{ns_xs_y} $$

where $n$ is the sample size, $\bar x$ is a sample mean, and $s_x$ is a sample SD. This is equal to the correlation of $\vec y$ with $\vec x$ because dot products and scalar multiplication are commutative.

Comment: Sample correlation would be more relevant than population correlation here.

Comment: @RichardHardy Okay.